# Numpy column wise multiplication

Tags: python, numpy

I have a rather large matrix (500000 * 24) as an `ndarray` and I want to multiply its cell with the corresponding column `min`. I have already done this with `for` loops but I keep reading that this is not the `NumPy` way of doing things.

Is there a proper way of doing such an operation (I might also want to substract a constant later)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can simply multiply your array with the minimum vector directly, an example is shown below.

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((500000, 24))
 # This returns an array of size 500,000 that is the row of 24 values
minimum = data.min(axis=1)

data = data * minimum
```

If you wish to create a `minimum` array of size 24 (where the minimum of the 500,000 values is taken) then you would choose `axis=0`.

This [set of slides](https://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/operations.html) discusses how such operations can work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
This will multiply with the minimum of all the array I want to multiply with the columns min

Comment: @tix3 I realised my mistake and have modifed the code now, does this work as you intended?

Answer (score 1):

Would normal multiply not do?

```
import numpy
a = numpy.random.random((4,2))
b = a * numpy.min(a,axis=0)
```